# jQuery JSON returning undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have data from my php json in this form:

```
string(170) "[{"id":"3","Name":"Kontrahent#322","NIP":"753","Adress":"Wiosenna29","PostCode":"20-201","City":"Olkusz","Phone":"12312312","Email":"jakub@edu.pl","Value":"0"}]"
```

and my function:

```
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
         var val = $('#test').val()       
         var id = $('#clientsname option').filter(function() {
            return this.value == val;
        }).data('id');
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                var data = xmlhttp.responseText;
                alert(data[0].Name);

            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getclients/"+id);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

alert(data[0].Name); or alert(data.Name); returning undefined. 
console.log(data);
return:

```
string(141) "[{"id":"1","Name":"Kontrahent #1","NIP":"735256985","Adress":"","PostCode":"","City":"","Phone":"777555888","Email":"e@mail.pl","Value":"0"}]"
```

I don't know what is wrong with my script. Anyone can hellp me?

Comment: Can you include the snippet of PHP that outputs your JSON?

Comment: What does console.log(data); returns?

Comment: your PHP JSON seems to be invalid.

Comment: Isn't `xmlhttp.responseText;` a string?! The property name suggests it ;)

Comment: Instead of using the stupid `alert` for debugging purposes, start using your browsers development console. That is _much_ more powerful. Start by logging data itself: `console.log(data);` That way you can see what is contained (here undecoded json text) and thus find the solution yourself ;-)

Comment: console.log(data); return something like this string(141) "[{"id":"1","Name":"Kontrahent #1","NIP":"735256985","Adress":"","PostCode":"","City":"","Phone":"777555888","Email":"e@mail.pl","Value":"0"}]"

Comment: in that case enclose json in {} like `"{[{"id":"1","Name":"Kontrahent #1","NIP":"735256985","Adress":"","PostCode":"","City":"","Phone":"777555888","E‌​mail":"e@mail.pl","Value":"0"}]}"`

Comment: as json root should be, as name suggests, a javascript object not array type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse response as JSON with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method, because `xmlhttp.responseText` is just a string:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        alert(data[0].Name);
    }
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/LygRQEu89LnQXW6TWDMa?p=preview

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s any time is unexpected token a or s, and I am sure that there is nowhere such a character.

Comment: thats s in string(170).. from your json.. yo need valid json string to return

Comment: @Kubol Make sure you output valid JSON string. Open `getclients/3` in separate tab and check that output is `[{"id":"3","Name":"Kontrahent#322","NIP":"753","Adress":"Wiosenna29","PostCode":"20-201","City":"Olkusz","Phone":"12312312","Email":"jakub@edu.pl","Value":"0"}]`.

Comment: Thanks, now it works great I changed little my JSON from getclients/3

Comment: what did you change 'little' ?

Answer (score 2):

`xmlhttp.responseText` returns text. If you want to parse the JSON, use `JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)`. Thus

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

        // var data = xmlhttp.responseText;
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        alert(data[0].Name);
    }
}
```

---

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s

Next,

```
string(170) "[{"id":"3","Name":"Kontrahent#322","NIP":"753","Adress":"Wiosenna29","PostCode":"20-201","City":"Olkusz","Phone":"12312312","Email":"jakub@edu.pl","Value":"0"}]"
```

is not JSON. This looks like `print_r` from PHP. Use `echo` instead if you have a valid JSON string, say by using `json_encode()` in PHP. Valid JSON will look like this:

```
[{"id":"3","Name":"Kontrahent#322","NIP":"753","Adress":"Wiosenna29","PostCode":"20-201","City":"Olkusz","Phone":"12312312","Email":"jakub@edu.pl","Value":"0"}]
```

Comment: on my PHP I have "return json_encode($data->result());"

Comment: that looks good, but don't you mean `echo json_encode($data->result());`? If this is the return from a function, make sure later it is echo'd, not print_r'd

Comment: How did you change your PHP if you accepted the other answer?

Comment: I can't accept 2 answers, but i changed var_dump($data) to echo $data; and now it's work "Make sure you output valid JSON string. Open getclients/3 in separate tab and check that output is" this give me idea

Comment: Ok, but I clearly said "This looks like print_r from PHP. Use echo instead" early on, just for the record - the two output the same thing for a string. That was the killer problem.

Comment: Thank you too for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Your json data is not correct.

```
$result = array("id"=>"3","Name"=>"Kontrahent#322","NIP"=>"753","Adress"=>"Wiosenna29","PostCode"=>"20-201","City"=>"Olkusz","Phone"=>"12312312","Email"=>"jakub@edu.pl","Value"=>"0");

return json_encode($result);
```

Retrieve json data from JSON.parse method

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        alert(data[0].Name);
    }
}
```